# How to fill the entire screen in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-room

I have a problem filling the entire screen in a reclycle view.

This is my xml code of the cardview and my view where the reclyclerview is:

CardView:

This is how it looks in the Ide Android studio:

Layout where the Reclycler view is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="30"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textIdPerson"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="30"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="30"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>






<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textAmount"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="ID"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textIdPerson"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="UserId"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textId"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Amount"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_row_main"/>
    


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="atras"
        android:onClick="@{viewmodel::back}"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Siguiente"
        android:onClick="@{viewmodel::next}"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0vf2.png)

But when I start the application on the device it looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yW0i.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity_main.xml(or any layout that hosts recyclerview) should look like this.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textIdPerson"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="UserID"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Id"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAtras"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ATRAS"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignature"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Signature" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

And list_item.xml layout should be something like below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textAmount"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textIdPerson"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="UserId"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textId"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Id"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your adapter class, Layout you designed for adapter class should have width match parent and three different textviews with equal width to hold values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `RecyclerView` has `layout_width` also set to `match_parent`.